# Easy calculation of simple asymetric table

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a programming question, but very math specific, so I posted it here.
I have a value that ranges from 1 to 10.
1 = 1. This is irregular in math terms, but it has to start somewhere. Maybe you could say the starting value is 1 and 0 is added.
2 = 2, because it is the result from the value before (1) and 1 is added.
3 = 4, because it is the result from the value before (2) and 2 is added.
4 = 7, because it is the result from the value before (4) and 3 is added.
5 = 11, because it is the result from the value before (7) and 4 is added.
6 = 16, because it is the result from the value before (11) and 5 is added.
7 = 22, because it is the result from the value before (16) and 6 is added.
8 = 29, because it is the result from the value before (22) and 7 is added.
9 = 37, because it is the result from the value before (29) and 8 is added.
10 = 46, because it is the result from the value before (37) and 9 is added.

So the question would be: How can I put that most easily into a formula without putting the complete table inside? I think it would be independend from a programming language, except there are some specific libraries that calculate such things. Has anyone an idea about that?

So it would work in a formula like this:

```
var value1 = 4;
var value2 = 7;
var result = value1 * (value2 translated to the table value);
// var result = 4 * 22; And not 4 * 7
```

edit: The correct formula is
a(n) = 1 + (n-1)*n/2

Comment: So am I correct to interpret that you're working with a sequence $a_n$ so that
$$
a_1 = 1 \qquad \text{and}\qquad a_{n+1} = a_{n} + n
$$? There is a very easy closed form for that ...

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I am searching for.

Comment: So perhaps it's this one? https://oeis.org/A152947

Comment: Yes. That is the solution, thank you very much :D

Comment: Just a comment for future: Please consider your mathematical notation. You wrote, for example "10 = 46". Ten is not equal to fourty-six. So instead, use something like $a_{10}=46$, meaning that the tenth element in a list/array has the value 46.

Comment: Ok, will consider that. Last time I had math in class is maybe 25 years ago. Couldn't remember such things.